# Make React Native Modal appear from top to bottom

Tags: react-native

I noticed that the [Modal](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html#animationtype) component's `animationType` property only allows for it to slide from bottom to top. How could I change the animation and make the modal appear from top to bottom?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't look like that component allows for that type of configuration.

One thing you could do is use the Animated library to create your own modal. You would set the `translateY` property to negative of of the height of the device, then animate the `translateY` value to 0:

```
openModal() {
    Animated.timing(this.state.modalY, {
        duration: 300,
        toValue: 0
     }).start();
  },

  closeModal() {
    Animated.timing(this.state.modalY, {
        duration: 300,
        toValue: -deviceHeight
     }).start();
  },
```

A full implementation is below:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Animated,
  Dimensions
} = React;

let deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  openModal() {
    Animated.timing(this.state.modalY, {
        duration: 300,
        toValue: 0
     }).start();
  },

  closeModal() {
    Animated.timing(this.state.modalY, {
        duration: 300,
        toValue: -deviceHeight
     }).start();
  },

  getInitialState(){
    return {
        modalY: new Animated.Value(-deviceHeight)
    }
  },

  render() {
     var Modal = <Animated.View style={[ styles.modal, { transform: [                        {translateY: this.state.modalY}] }]}>
                                <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.closeModal } underlayColor="green" style={ styles.button }>
                    <Text style={ styles.buttonText }>Close Modal</Text>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
                             </Animated.View>

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.openModal } underlayColor="green" style={ styles.button }>
        <Text style={ styles.buttonText }>Show Modal</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>
      { Modal }
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white'
  },
  modal: {
    height: deviceHeight,
    width: deviceWidth,
    position: 'absolute',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    backgroundColor: '#ededed',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: what is the initial state modalY's value?

Comment: This is a live demo of your code (refreshed synthax) without any changes nor improvement: https://snack.expo.io/@kopax/f7abfe  => result [ios: NOK, android: NOK, web: NOK]

Answer (score 1):

Use `react-native-modal` community package. It has built in this feature. Set `animationIn={'slideInDown'}, animationInTiming={300}` properties.